# Fit a linear regression model using maximum likelihood

Tags: python, mle

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
y   x1  x2  x3
0   185.00  2.3 -75.8   1
1   152.00  -7.9    -59.9   1
2   32.80   -1.6    -11.0   0
3   183.00  8.3 -88.6   0
4   193.00  3.8 -71.9   1
5   98.20   6.7 -41.1   0
6   105.00  -4.4    -46.4   0
7   156.00  7.0 -65.5   1
8   29.00   -6.3    -17.1   0
9   68.00   -4.1    -32.9   0
10  29.40   2.1 -11.6   0
```

I am not sure how to use maximum likelihood to fit the following model [image] and find the estimates for betas and sigma.

I am not sure how to get started. Can anyone give me some guidance on this?

Comment: maximum likelihood will lead to `beta = (XTX)-1XTy`, so you can just use sklearn to fit this data

Comment: Thank you @OsmanMamun. Can you provide a little more detail about how to use sklearn to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

`X` and `y` are np array

```
>>> from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
>>> reg = LinearRegression().fit(X, y)
>>> y_hat = reg.predict(X)
```

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html